# Choose a different default Entity Form in the CRM Dynamics 365 Mobile App and Web?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics365-app-mobile, dynamics-crm-uci

We're just getting into making our CRM 365 OnPrem environment work well using the Mobile App, but the forms we display on web just don't layout well on the 365 Mobile App.  I hoped there would be some way to select a different Default Form for the Mobile App and Web depending on how the user comes in, but I haven't found anyway to do this.

Makes since that the two different environments wouldn't be laid out the same way, so I'd like to build a Form for Mobile App and one for Web so I can arrange the fields accordingly.  Just no logical way to use the same layout on both.

Thanks for any advise.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can have two different forms, design the layout (tab, section, fields) for Web & Mobile (UCI) app in two different forms
2. For UCI app - we can control the form to render, by choosing the Mobile layout form as the only entity Asset. [Read more](https://www.powerobjects.com/2017/05/30/creating-custom-apps-using-app-designer-in-dynamics-365/)
3. In Web - still user can switch between multiple forms using form selector, we may [need script](https://www.magnetismsolutions.com/blog/gayanperera/2013/07/24/how-to-switch-a-dynamics-crm-form-based-on-a-value) to land the users in the required form on form load using [navigate()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/clientapi/reference/formcontext-ui-formselector/navigate)